# android TextInputEditText unable to get text from Paste action

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

Hi android developers
I have a **TextInputEditText** that has **TextInputLayout** parent. I am trying to paste phone number, which I have already copied, into **TextInputEditText**. If focus of **TextInputEditText** change, the input will be empty :/

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/userNameInputLayout"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Register"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                        app:hintTextColor="@color/app_text_moremuted"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:theme="@style/MyHintStyle">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:maxLength="11"
                            android:inputType="phone"
                            android:id="@+id/userNameInput"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                            android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
                            android:textColor="@color/app_text"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_mobile_gray"
                             />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Amazing point is that the text color of **TextInputEditText** is **Black**. But when data is pasted, its color is **gray(like hint color)**

It's about one week I am searching for it but no answer...

Tnx anyone can help...